# How to configure Bitbucket app password with SourceTree?

Tags: ssh, configuration, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, two-factor-authentication

I enabled two-factor authentication in Bitbucket, then created an app password. Where should I configure this app password in SourceTree?

Comment: Not the right place to ask, you should visit atlassian forum/support

Comment: @DarjanBogdan why not? This is a software used by programmers and therefore falling into the topic of SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 8):

Please follow the below steps suggested by Atlassian -

[image]

[image]

Source: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/

Comment: These instructions aren't working for me.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone finding this in 2021, another alternative (If you've been using other Bitbucket repositories all the while without having this problem). My issue is that I still had a very old repo still using the HTTPS git URL.

For example, issuing `git remote -v` in my legacy repository revealed something like:

```
origin  https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/myrepository.git (fetch)
origin  https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/myrepository.git (push)
```

Simply take the SSH version of your repository instead and set it with (using above url as an example):

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:myusername/myusername.git
```

You can do a sanity check by issuing `git remote -v` again to confirm that the new origin URL has been set.

Once this is set, you should be able to push to your remove without issues.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use your app password instead of your account password when you configure the repository.